# "few" is a past tense of which verb?

Tags: meaning

In a [WSJ](https://www.wsj.com/articles/unworthy-republic-review-jacksons-eminent-domain-11584717127) article, I read the following sentence:

> One hunter few a knife, pulled the man’s hair taut, and cut off his scalp.

My search in dictionaries and on the web have failed me.  Which verb is "few" a past tense of?

Comment: I'd be surprised if that were not a typo for "drew."

Comment: This is probably it!  How silly of me.  Thank you.

Comment: This is the kind of typo you get with auto-correcting software and OCR approximations. "Few" is a legitimate word, so it doesn't get flagged, but the software can't figure out why it doesn't really work there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This must be a typo, because I have never heard 'few' used as a verb. They probably meant to write 'drew', which is the past tense of 'draw', or to pull out.